# Как правильно считывать введенные пользователем данные?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть три InputField, куда пользователь будет вводить данные. Скорость, расстояние и время респауна.
Как правильно организовать их использование в коде? У меня было несколько проблем:

1. Где должны инициализироваться эти переменные? Каждая в своем скрипте (например, скорость в скрипте Move) или в одном? И как их все конвертировать в int? Делать список string ов и пробегаться по нему?
2. Чтобы работать с значением, введенным в поле, я переменные делала static, но такой подход не понравился. Кажется, что он неправильный. Как правильно получить значения из другого скрипта?

Извиняюсь, если что то непонятно написала

Answer (score 1):

У `InputField` есть свойство `Content Type` и если оно `Decimal Number` то имея гарантию, можно смело сразу парсить его значение в `float`.

Учитывая что это блок связанных данных логично объединить их в `struct`. Учитывая что их нужно сохранить, проще всего это сделать через `PlayerPrefs`, а если сохраненных данных нет то подставить какие нибудь дефолтные настройки.